# Pumping Lemma for CF language exercise

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I have this language
$$ B=\{x\in \{a,b,c\}^*:(x\text{ not contains } aabb \text{ or } bbcc \text{ or } aaaa) \land \#(a,x)=\#(b,x)=\#(c,x)\} $$
The notation $ \#(s,x) $ indicates the number of occurrences of simbol $s$ in $x$.

I know that it isn't a CF language, but I can't find a string to use with Pumping Lemma in order to demonstrate it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A standard shorter notation for $\#(a,x)$ is $|x|_a$.

Answer (score 0):

$(ac)^n(b)^n$

Test the substrings and you should notice that pumping causes #a && #c != #b, #a !=  #c && #a != #b etc

Comment: This string has a problem. If I take vwx = "acb", I can take w as empty string, v="ac", x="b". In this case for all i I have $ v^iwx^i $ = $(ac)^ib^i$ and it is inside the language

Comment: One of the pumping lemma pre-conditions states |vwx| <= n.
With the string "acb" you're assigning n <- 1, but |acb| = 3 > 1 --> 3 > n. Therefore, the string "acb" is not valid to test the pumping lemma for this language

Comment: @gianfranco: the constant in the pumping lemma is the pumping constant (usually designated `p`), which is a feature of the grammar itself. It's not assigned from an example string. You cannot assume that it is less than 3.

Comment: The example above was intended to be considered as  (ac)^p b^p, which you can apply the pumping lemma to and demonstrate that L Is not CF. if you assume p = 1 you can not use abc as string, otherwise you can use the pumping lemma as explained above

Comment: @Gianfranco: Yes, but you cannot assume that `p` is 1. `p` is a feature of a particular grammar, not of the language, and you don't have a grammar at hand to ask what its value of `p` is. Instead, you need to prove that there is no context-free grammar for that language. "Assume `p` is one" only lets you make a statement about those (hypothetical) grammars whose pumping constant is 1. Since there might not be any such grammar, the fact that if there were such a grammar, you couldn't prove its non-existence doesn't get you very far :-)

Answer (score 0):

The "usual" sentence to pump for $a^nb^nc^n$ (or variants, including ones where only the counts need to match) is something like
$$a^pb^pc^p$$
but that won't quite work in this case because of the substring restrictions. So the challenge is to find a variant on that sentence which also satisfies the requirement that there is no $aabb$, $bbcc$ nor $aaaa$. The first two can easily be accomplished by reversing the string ($c^pb^pa^p$); to deal with the prohibition on $aaaa$, we need to use something like
$$c^{2p}b^p(baa)^p$$
which has $2p$ instances of each alphabet symbol. As with $a^pb^pc^p$, it is evident that no substring of length $p$ can contain more than two different symbols, with the result that it cannot be pumped without making the symbol counts different from each other.